# Why do I get unidentified image error and most recent call last? UnknownError: UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing, image-classification

I am working on medical images. I was wondering weather there are any corrupted images in the package I received. However, as I try to check, I can not seem to be able to identify the bad image(s).

I run the code

```
folder_path = '/home/kenan/Desktop/COV19D/validation/non-covid'
extensions4 = []
for fldr in os.listdir(folder_path):
    sub_folder_path = os.path.join(folder_path, fldr)
    for filee in os.listdir(sub_folder_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(sub_folder_path, filee)
        print('** Path: {}  **'.format(file_path), end="\r", flush=True)
        im = Image.open(file_path)
        rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
        if filee.split('.')[1] not in extensions4:       
            extensions4.append(filee.split('.')[1])
```

I get the following error after going through all images in the provided path:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-16-2498ba801223>", line 8, in <module>
    im = Image.open(file_path)

  File "/home/kenan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2967, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file '/home/kenan/Desktop/COV19D/validation/non-covid/ct_scan_9/._9.jpg'
```

I try to look for the image  '._9.jpg' but I can not really find that. I only find the image named  '9.jpg'. Eventually, even if I delete that image, the exact same error shows up.

During the training of the model and after finishing the first epoch similar error shows up. How can I continue training my model with these images?

Thank you

Comment: Files with a name starting with a dot are hidden files. Did you try `rm /home/kenan/Desktop/COV19D/validation/non-covid/ct_scan_9/._9.jpg`?

Comment: I have to run remove 'rm' on two files actually. But now it seems to be working. Thank you.